# Where to find datasets for creating carto vl maps?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uses-of-open-data

Is there any way to download example datasets like nyc taxi and origin-destination data? (Like those that show flight paths from and to some cities) I think it'd help me greatly if I could somehow get those data and try to create VL animations on my own.

Comment: "Like those that show flight paths from and to some cities" please share where can I find them

Comment: look at some of the questions that have been answered here seeking gis data is my first thought. my second is, are you asking for carto files? pretty sure they are not open-source.

Comment: 1. Flight paths examples from CartoDB
https://carto.com/blog/jets-and-datelines/
http://flightroutes.geographica.gs/                                                                     
2. Yeah so I've got cartodb setup here locally on Ubuntu server. Data source doesn't have to be specifically Carto but I want to use VL animations with it if possible. Like you said, CartoDB stand-alone installation is open-sourced but I don't think the data maps are open to public.

Comment: I'd contact the major taxi companies that service NYC and see if they publish this data. Otherwise, I'm not sure how you'd find this data-- taxispotting isn't a major trend in the US... at least not yet.